# Apply Data Annotations Server Side Only

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations

I have a ViewModel with a number of data annotaions:

```
    [MaxLength(100)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a title.")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(250)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a job.")]
    public string Job { get; set; }
```

However, I only want to apply the validation checks server-side with the ModelState.IsValid method. This is because particular sections of the form may not apply, as indicated by a bool backed checkbox. If the "SectionApplies" checkbox is not ticked, then I dont want the validation errors preventing the rest of the form from being submitted.

How can I acheive this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch off client-side unobtrusive validation on a field by field basis by overriding the `data-val='true'` Data Annotation attribute for the field in the view.

```html
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title, new { @data_val = "false" })
```